# How to use `policy_definition_reference` block with templatefile(path,vars) syntax

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-policy

I’m working on setting multiple tagging policy definitions using Terraform. I have mentioned the tag definitions with policy definition id’s and parameters in custom json file.

**tag_definitions.json**

```
[
  {
    "parameters": {
      "tagName": {
        "value": "cost_center"
      },
      "tagValue": {
        "value": "${cost_center}"
      }
    },
    "policyDefinitionId": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX"
  }
]
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_policy_set_definition" "tag_definition" {
  name         = "${var.subscription_name}-tag-definition"
  display_name = "${var.subscription_name}-tag-definition"
  description  = "Append the default tags definition"
  policy_type  = "Custom"
  policy_definitions = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/tag_definitions.json",
  { cost_center = var.cost_center })
  metadata = <<METADATA
    { "category" : "Tags" }
  METADATA
  lifecycle { ignore_changes = [metadata] }
}
```

In the above main.tf file, the `policy_definitions` argument is deprecated now. Instead of that I want to use `policy_definition_reference` argument.

I have followed [azurerm_policy_set_definition](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/policy_set_definition)  documentation. But this documentation doesn't contain the information about how to set the multiple policy definitions using "policy_definition_reference" block.

I want to use `policy_definition_reference` block with my custom tag_definitions.json file along with parameter values.

Based on the below comments I have tried using the below code. But it is not working as expected.

**tag_definitions_params.json**

```
 [
  {
    "parameters": {
      "tagName": {
        "value": "common.cost_center"
      },
      "tagValue": {
        "value": "${cost_center}"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "parameters": {
      "tagName": {
        "value": "common.env_type"
      },
      "tagValue": {
        "value": "${env_type}"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_policy_set_definition" "tag_definition" {
  name         = "${var.subscription_name}-tag-definition"
  display_name = "${var.subscription_name}-tag-definition"
  description  = "Append the default tags definition"
  policy_type  = "Custom"
  #policy_definitions = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/tag_definitions.json",
  #{ cost_center = var.cost_center, env_type = var.env_type, owner_accountname = var.owner_accountname, product = var.product })
  policy_definition_reference {
    policy_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/XXXXXXXX"
    parameter_values     = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/tag_definitions_params.json",
                            { 
                              cost_center = var.cost_center,
                              env_type = var.env_type
                            })
  }
  policy_definition_reference {
    policy_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/XXXXXXXXX"
    parameter_values     = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/tag_definitions_params.json",
                            { 
                              cost_center = var.cost_center,
                              env_type = var.env_type
                            })
  }
  metadata = <<METADATA
    { "category" : "Tags" }
  METADATA
  lifecycle { ignore_changes = [metadata] }
}
```

Comment: do you receive an error?

Comment: @MoonHorse, I'm getting this error `expanding `policy_definition_reference`: unmarshalling `parameter_values`: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type map[string]*policy.ParameterValuesValue'`.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the information about "policy_definition_reference" block, here:

> A policy_definition_reference block supports the following:
>
> policy_definition_id - (Required) **The ID of the policy definition or
> policy set definition** that will be included in this policy set
> definition.
>
> parameter_values - (Optional) Parameter values for the referenced
> policy rule. This field is a JSON string that allows you to assign
> parameters to this policy rule.
>
> reference_id - (Optional) A unique ID within this policy set
> definition for this policy definition reference.
>
> policy_group_names - (Optional) A list of names of the policy
> definition groups that this policy definition reference belongs to.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/policy_set_definition#policy_definition_reference

You can as well use as below:

```
policy_definition_id ="/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX" 
parameter_values = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/tag_definitions_params.json"
```

So you need to just contain your parameter in a the json file and set the id of the policy set in the terraform code with `policy_definition_id` property.

Comment: Thanks MoonHorse, In my question I have clear mentioned how to use multiple policy definitions id's inside `policy_definition_reference` block.

Comment: @Pradeep , policy set or  policy initiatives is a set of multiple policies. As it is written in the documentation, you have to pass the id of the policy set definition. Is it clear?

Comment: @Pradeep, You can use also policy_definition_reference block multiple times. Have you tried that?

Comment: I'm using this code `policy_definitions = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/tag_definitions.json",
  { cost_center = var.cost_center })` to assign multiple policies definitions. In the same manner I want to use `policy_definition_reference` block.

Comment: If you use policy_definition_reference block multiple times, obviously it works. But I have to use more than 20 times. Instead of that, I'm looking for iteration concept.

Comment: policy_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX" , parameter_values = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/tag_definitions.json" . You need to do like that. So you need to just contain your parameter in a single json file and set the id of the policy set in the terraform code

Comment: @Pradeep Let me know if it works like that

Comment: Pls look at the updates question.